# Access an already loaded user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working an Asp.net project, I am loading two user controls into another ascx control. First, I am loading the `control1.ascx` and then the control2. After loading both of them inside control2.ascx I want to access a function that reloads some data of control1. I am doing it with the following code:

```
 private ASP.control1_ascx tree; 
 tree = (ASP.control1_ascx)LoadControl("control1.ascx");
 tree.aload();
```

When I debug the code, it seems that it calls the aload() function and updates the data. But the problem is that I cannot see them after the function is called, instead I can see the correct data after a postback event. Why is this happens?. Is there a solution to see them when I call the function ?

Comment: I think you need to check the events in the life cycle of the controller. Perhaps you're setting the data of a child controller and after that the parent controller refreshed and resets that data

Comment: hmm, i checked the events , the last thing that is executed is the aload() !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried creating a delegate event in each of your user controls and then use this to rebind the data?

In your usercontrol:

```
public delegate void RefreshRequired(object sender, any other params to pass to event method)

public event OnRefreshRequired OnRefreshRequired;
```

In your Page_Load of ASPX

```
UserControl.OnRefreshRequired+= TAB TWICE;
```

Implement code in this method to refresh the data in the user controls

Comment: what is the difference to access it by events and by accessing it with the way i tried ?

Comment: I would need to see your code, but I have used this approach in the past and it works fine.